# Call a personal Java method from eXistdb XQuery Processor

Tags: java, import, xquery

I have noticed i can call from eXistdb XQuery processor any Java classes, i need just to declare a namespace like the following:

```
declare namespace string="java:java.lang.String";
```

I've imported all the methods from the class *String*.

Now comes the question: is there a way to import my own classes? For example, if i made that class:

```
package example.model.A

class A1 {
    public static example() { ... }
}
```

Is there a way to use the method *example* inside my xquery? Can i point the namespace to my personal class?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on "Calling Java Methods from XQuery" and "Creating Modules in Java" (see http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xquery.xml).

Comment: Yes, but i haven't found how to specify the path from my package.

Comment: I really don't know the answer, so I have two suggestions if you don't hear from anyone else: 1. Search the exist-open archives via http://exist-open.markmail.org/. For example, a search for "calling java methods" leads to this possibly fruitful discussion: http://markmail.org/message/sozy6oz5rejznmxv. 2. Join exist-open and post your message there, which has a larger community of people doing what you're trying to do. Subscribe at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open.

Comment: I believe you add you jar to the lib seach directions for adding RenderX as a sample. That would be the same.